# How to determine if a InputStream contains JSON data?

Tags: java, json, unicode, utf-8, inputstream

How do I check if the data behind a `java.io.InputStream` (from `File`, `URL`, ..) is of type JSON?

---

Of course to be complete the best would be to load the whole data of the stream and try to validate it as JSON (e.g checking for closing bracket `}`). Since the stream source might be very big (a GeoJSON file with a size of 500MB) this eventually end in a burning machine.

To avoid this I wrote a small method that only takes the first character of the `InputStream` as UTF-8/16/32 and tests if it is a `{` according to [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) (which is referenced and updated by [RFC 7159](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt)) to determine its JSONness:

> JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode. The default encoding is UTF-8.

And:

> Since the first two characters of a JSON text will always be ASCII
>      characters [RFC0020], it is possible to determine whether an octet
>      stream is UTF-8, UTF-16 (BE or LE), or UTF-32 (BE or LE) by looking
>      at the pattern of nulls in the first four octets.

```
       00 00 00 xx  UTF-32BE
       00 xx 00 xx  UTF-16BE
       xx 00 00 00  UTF-32LE
       xx 00 xx 00  UTF-16LE
       xx xx xx xx  UTF-8
```

The method is:

```
public static boolean mightBeJSON(InputStream stream) {
    try {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1];

        stream.read(bytes);
        if (bytes[0] == 0x7B) {
            return true;
        }

        stream.read(bytes);
        if (bytes[0] == 0x7B) {
            return true;
        }

        stream.read(bytes);
        stream.read(bytes);
        if (bytes[0] == 0x7B) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Nothing to do;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Until now my machine is still not burning, BUT:

- Is there anything wrong with this approach/implementation?
- May there be any problems in some situations?
- Anything to improve?

Comment: RFC 4627 is **obsolete**. Please refer to [RFC 7159](http://rfc7159.net/rfc7159) instead.

Comment: I followed your link to [RFC 7159](http://rfc7159.net/rfc7159). Am I the only one who doesn't trust RFCs with a website not of [plain, unformated text](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt)? :D

Comment: Yep, it's only you! ;-)

Comment: I do not like reading plain-text versions of RFCs, I prefer reading HTML versions instead (such as [this one](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159)), makes it much easier to navigate around. I also prefer to read RFCs from IETF directly, not third-party sites.

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 7159](http://rfc7159.net/rfc7159) states:

> **8. String and Character Issues**
>
> **8.1 Character Encoding**
>
> JSON text **SHALL** be encoded in UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32. The
>   default encoding is UTF-8, and JSON texts that are encoded in UTF-8
>   are interoperable in the sense that they will be read successfully by
>   the maximum number of implementations; there are many implementations
>   that cannot successfully read texts in other encodings (such as UTF-16
>   and UTF-32).
>
> Implementations **MUST NOT** add a byte order mark to the beginning of
>   a JSON text. In the interests of interoperability, implementations
>   that parse JSON texts MAY ignore the presence of a byte order mark
>   rather than treating it as an error.

This doesn't answer your question per say, but I hope it can help in your logic.